# Looping through Grunt tasks

Tags: javascript, loops, gruntjs, css-sprites

Currently new to Grunt and looking at setting up a task to construct CSS sprites from a collection of source files (within a common folder structure).

To do this I've been using grunt-spritesmith: https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-spritesmith.

As of now, I have the task watching a specific folder and constructing sprites and SCSS partials fine.

**My question:** Is it possible to loop through an array of site names and pass them into the tasks below - without duplicating the task for each site?

```
grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sprite: {

        normal: {
            src: 'site1/images/sprite/1x/*.png',
            destImg: 'site1/images/site1-sprite.png',
            destCSS: 'styles/scss/site1/sprite/_spritesmith.scss',
            algorithm: 'binary-tree',
            padding: 20,
            cssFormat: 'scss',
            engine: 'pngsmith',
            cssOpts: {
                cssClass: function(item) {
                    return '.' + item.name;
                },
            },
        },

        retina: {
            src: 'site1/images/sprite/2x/*.png',
            destImg: 'site1/images/site1-sprite-2x.png',
            destCSS: 'styles/scss/site1/sprite/_spritesmith-retina.scss',
            algorithm: 'binary-tree',
            padding: 40,
            cssFormat: 'scss',
            engine: 'pngsmith',
            cssOpts: {
                functions: false,
            },
        },

    },

});
```

I have a collection of around 15-20 sites, so duplicating each task twice for standard and retina sprites has soon bloated my Gruntfile. Javascript isn't my forte, so every solution thus far has failed to work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you will notice that the `grunt.initConfig` function takes an object literal as the input, as such you can grammatically build a config object before passing it to initConfig

something like

```
var _ = require('lodash'),
    tasks = require('mytasks'),
    abunchOftasks = require('anotherSetOfTasks');


var combined = _.merge(tasks, abunchOftasks ) //a deep extend

grunt.initConfig(combined)
```

where `require('mytasks')` and `require('anotherSetOfTasks')` return an `{}` with a bunch of defined tasks, vars, etc. Such as :

```
//mytasks
module.exports=   { 
  sprite: {
    normal: {
        src: 'site1/images/sprite/1x/*.png',
        destImg: 'site1/images/site1-sprite.png',
        destCSS: 'styles/scss/site1/sprite/_spritesmith.scss',
        algorithm: 'binary-tree',
        padding: 20,
        cssFormat: 'scss',
        engine: 'pngsmith',
        cssOpts: {
            cssClass: function(item) {
                return '.' + item.name;
            },
        },
    },
  }
};

//anotherSetOfTasks
module.exports = {
  sprite: {
    retina: {
        src: 'site1/images/sprite/2x/*.png',
        destImg: 'site1/images/site1-sprite-2x.png',
        destCSS: 'styles/scss/site1/sprite/_spritesmith-retina.scss',
        algorithm: 'binary-tree',
        padding: 40,
        cssFormat: 'scss',
        engine: 'pngsmith',
        cssOpts: {
            functions: false,
        },
    },
  }
};
```

**EDIT** Oops may have mis understood a little, but the basic princible still applies. you can create a function that generates the task from a site name. I would loop through an array of names as you suggest and create a new piece of the config, then combine each object into a single object undert the `sprite` property. Does that make sense?